# Info about interfacing Fanuc R-2000iC/165F with ROS

Tags: ros, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I already got the answers through direct contact, but as requested, it is worth to share the answers (thanks @gvdhoorn !)

I wanted to know if a package is already available for the R-2000iC/165F and also R-2000iC/210F, or alternatively build it myself.

For the 165F version, it is now available in `fanuc_experimental`

The 210F version should have the same Xacro as the 165F version, but needs to have joint limits changed (and inertia if needed). I will PR it as soon as I have tested and confirmed working.

The process needed to build a URDF from scratch:

- try to get a SolidWorks model. It will be infinitely more efficient to convert
- don't use SolidWorks or any other tool, it's not needed and will complicate the work
- if you can get a SolidWorks model, use any SolidWorks viewer and
  export the parts of the links to individual STL files (binary STL)
- use a mesh editing tool to transform their origins to where the
  joint origins are (you can do this using the diagrams showsn in the
  'basic specifications' section of any operating manual of your robot
  which shows the lengths of joints
- use existing support package xacro files as a template (for the structure. If it is a variant, do not create a separate package. Variants of a series/model go into a single robot support package.

Hope this helps others

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370494/info-about-interfacing-fanuc-r-2000ic/165f-with-ros/) by [dq18](https://answers.ros.org/users/68834/dq18/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may be interested to know that I pushed a new support package for the R-2000iC/165F.

See [ros-industrial/fanuc_experimental/fanuc_r2000ic_support](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc_experimental/tree/b24fd8df7d28b3085a61609bc3719b980dab0efc/fanuc_r2000ic_support).

---

Edit: [ros-industrial/fanuc_experimental#59](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc_experimental/pull/59) may be a nice PR to look at, it adds support for another variant of the R-2000iC: the `270F`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-28**:\

> For the 165F version, it is now available in `fanuc_experimental`

Oh, I only now see you already noticed that.

**Comment by [dq18](https://answers.ros.org/users/68834/dq18/) on 2021-01-31**:
Yes, thanks for that. I will mark this topic as answered